# What should be done to have 'Value' in the enumeration?

Tags: scala, enumeration

This code does not compile:

```
object Token extends Enumeration {
    type ID = Value
    val Key, Value = Value
}
```

error: recursive value Value needs type

What should be done to have 'Value' in the enumeration ?

Comment: Value is a protected final field into Enumeration, so you will not be able to override it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible because `Value` is already a final member of `Enumeration` - the obvious suggestion is to call your field `Val` instead.

Comment: Very sad. I wanted to rely on the content of the toString() method of the enumeration. I wanted it to coincide with the class name on the companion class. I have to look for another solution.